# Where I can get Tesseract binaries for Debian 6 64bit?

Tags: debian, ocr, tesseract

I used apt-get to install Tesseract but it's not really working. Maybe I could just download binaries somewhere, put in a dir and use this way?

What's wrong with my Tesseract now:

```
tesseract --help
tesseract:Error:Usage:tesseract imagename outputbase [-l lang] [configfile [[+|-]varfile]...]
```

and

```
tesseract test.tif out2.txt -l pol
Unable to load unicharset file /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/pol.unicharset
```

I have downloaded and unpacked Polish language into the dir above, but the only pol.* is pol.traindeddate.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should install also the Polish language support using `apt`:

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr-polsudo apt search tesseract-ocr-*
```

For other language list language packages and select the one than is matching your language:

```
 sudo apt search tesseract-ocr-*
```

Example for Romanian:

```
sudo apt search tesseract-ocr-* | grep "Romanian" -b1
```

will give

```
7900-tesseract-ocr-ron/xenial,xenial 3.04.00-2 all
7946:  tesseract-ocr language files for Romanian
7990-
```

and then

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr-ron
```